# Update Manager doesn't work "ImportError: No module named 'codecs'"

Tags: apt, python

Whenever I try `sudo update-manager` it returns:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
```

I tried the following commands:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update # no errors
sudo apt-get clean # no errors
sudo apt-get install -fy # same error
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3 # same error
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg apt update-manager python # same error
sudo apt-get autoremove # same error
sudo apt-get upgrade # same error
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.4 #E: Internal Error, No file name for python3.4:amd64
sudo apt-get install python3.4 # same error (Dependency problems )
python --version #Python 2.7.6
sudo apt-get -f install # same error (Dependency problems )
```

I didn't modify the `__ init __.py` file .

Here is a full error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for user: 
Building dependency tree                  
Reading state information... 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3.4 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package python3.4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.4 (>= 3.4.0-0~); however:
  Package python3.4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up screen-resolution-extra (0.17.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package screen-resolution-extra (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 update-manager depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.4
 python3
 screen-resolution-extra
 update-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I tried `gksu update manager` as one of the members recommended ; and it returns `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: I added a space between __ init __ .py ; so the editor doesn't make it __init__.py

Comment: Could you check how many versions of python do you have on your system? It seems 2.7.6, but apt is using a messy 3.4, try `ls /usr/lib` command and look at python directory. Also could you update your question with Ubuntu version?

Comment: here is the `ls /usr/lib/python*` output : [http://pastebin.com/DK1mqNBe](http://pastebin.com/DK1mqNBe)

Comment: @Letizia I tried `lsb_release -a` . Sadly I get the same error msg which is `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
Aborted`

Comment: Could you post `echo $PYTHONPATH` and `echo $PYTHONHOME` commands output? Does it ever work? What did you do before update-manager starts to not working?

Comment: @Letizia Both commands don't return anything.My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation was a week old when I posted this question . I  installed  it in my father PC since I believed that he is less experienced with dealing with suspicious websites and all that. Obviously Ubuntu is more secure and doesn't need an anti-virus. . Here all of the commands before things got messy .`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` , `apt-get install unity` and `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia* ` .Update manager worked fine for couple of days then I got a red - sign .

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your filesystem has been damaged. Check the logs for hints, and also look inside `/lost+found`.
The solution is to reinstall the package containing the missing module.

Find the Ubuntu package providing this file:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py
```

Reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3.4-minimal
```

Also, reinstall the packages that provide any other files found in `lost+found`